# SQL Server : error "Error converting data type varbinary to numeric"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've got a trouble with deleting/updating the particular row in my table.
The table is small and simple:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy 
(
    "numemv" NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "control_summ" DECIMAL NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "active" CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    "departid" INT NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX "UNIQUE" ("numemv")
)
```

The row that I can't delete/update:

```
numemv   control_summ active departid
00499038 400000       1      0
```

I tried to manage in this ways:

```
UPDATE dbo.atm_control_summs 
SET departid = 13 
WHERE departid = 0

DELETE FROM dbo.atm_control_summs 
WHERE departid = 0

UPDATE dbo.atm_control_summs 
SET departid = 13 
WHERE numemv = '00499038'

DELETE FROM dbo.atm_control_summs 
WHERE numemv = '00499038'
```

But always I get the error:

> Error SQL (8114): Error converting data type varbinary to numeric.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Why you have used `" "` in create table statement. And what does this mean `NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL`?? Means null not allowed and by default null values inserted

Comment: Also, don't `SET` values in `DELETE` statements.

Comment: Does the table has any triggers?

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai: " "  says it is a column.

Comment: Index name identifier `"UNIQUE"` is not accepted.

Comment: @Kumar `" " says it is a column` What do you mean ? Columns names don't have to be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: @X.L.Ant : Check the link for the QUOTED_IDENTIFIER .. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx

Comment: Well this table was not created by me. I just use it in my app.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect code (SET in DELETE) - just a result of copy/paste ))  Correct delete code does not work too: `DELETE FROM dbo.atm_control_summs WHERE numemv = '00499038'`

Comment: There are no triggers

Comment: I see nothing in the code you posted that can possibly generate the error you say you are getting.   Most likely you are conflating this code error with something that is happening in some other code that you have not included in your post.